# Can't connect to docker daemon

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I installed docker and docker-compose on my ec2 instance. I have also started docker but when I try docker-compose I get an error:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-16-150 ~]$ sudo service docker start
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-16-150 ~]$ docker --version
Docker version 1.9.1, build a34a1d5/1.9.1
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-16-150 ~]$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version: 1.4.2
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-16-150 ~]$ docker-compose -p docker -f my-compose.yml up -d
Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localunixsocket - is it running?

If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-16-150 ~]$ sudo docker-compose -p docker -f my-compose.yml up -d
sudo: docker-compose: command not found
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-16-150 ~]$ echo $DOCKER_HOST
```

I've tried the command with sudo as well but it doesn't recognize `docker-compose` as a command

I have not set any `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable. I am not sure if I need to..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to run the actually command with sudo:

```
sudo docker-compose -p docker -f my-compose.yml up -d
```

Docker runs as root on your Linux system, so all the interactions with the running daemon need to be as root. You can run the commands as a user, but you're not interacting with the running system!

You can install docker-compose on Amazon Linux with:

```
curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.4.0/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` | sudo tee /usr/local/bin/docker-compose > /dev/null
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Comment: when I do sudo I get an error `sudo: docker-compose: command not found`

Comment: You might have installed it as a user... Can you install docker-compose for the system?

Comment: This is how I installed docker-compose: `sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.4.0/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` | sudo tee /usr/local/bin/docker-compose > /dev/null && sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose` from this gist https://gist.github.com/hitsujiwool/81fcab49f9ccf8ac5835

Comment: I installed it just now with two commands `curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.4.0/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` | sudo tee /usr/local/bin/docker-compose > /dev/null
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose` and it works with `sudo docker-compose`

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. I'm not sure what the problem is. I've asked another question with all details though  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36414531/sudo-docker-compose-command-not-found